# React Executing a method inside a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyComponent extends Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      isActive: false,
    }
  }

  showMyComponent() {
    this.setState({
      isActive: true,
    });
  }

  hideMyComponent() {
    this.setState({
      isActive: false,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Compoent Here</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Now, on my index.js I am adding several components.

```
...

<Header />
<Nave />
```

Can I now do something like this here:

```
MyComponent.showMyComponent();
```

Like you normally call a function?

If not, how is this done?

Comment: Seems like there should be a different approach to this. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't think that would work, you would have to call the method on a class instance. `MyComponent.showMyComponent` would only work with a static method, but your method isn't static, and couldn't be, because then it would have no access to the state.

Comment: I agree with Omri, please let us know what the context is

Comment: Normally when you want to show a component you just add <Component /> but what about if the component is already there and I just want to call one of it's methods to do something with it or hide it or something ... I was thinking I can then just can the method inside the component?

Comment: Then you should pass a prop to it and do the logic you want inside `componentWillReceiveProps` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use references. In your `render()` method you can get the ref. e.g.

```
<MyComponent ref={ref => {this.myComponent = ref}}/>
```

You need to create a field `myComponent` and assign it to it. With that you can call it like `this.myComponent.showMyComponent()`

See here [Refs and the DOM](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Answer (score 0):

## Use State

You are thinking about react wrong. You should not have to call a components function like this ever.

You can pass a prop to the component that will make the component hide or show.

or wrap the component in a `if` in the parent. Use the parents state to hide or show the component.

Like

`if (someCondition) {
    <MyComponent />
}`

Comment: What about if there's no condition...if at some point I just want to put it there? Like if I did ... <Header /><Nav /> ... doSomething();

Comment: there has to be a condition. if there is an on and off there must be a reason and therefore a condition.

Answer (score 0):

It's doable, even if some people hates this option, cause it's not the official React way, true.

> You can define any public method on your component classes (such as a reset method on a Typeahead) and call those public methods through refs (such as this.refs.myTypeahead.reset()). In most cases, it's clearer to use the built-in React data flow instead of using refs imperatively.

But However, thinking out of the box, is not forbidden so **you can** use **refs** for this.

```
class Parent extends Component {
  onSomeThing() {
    // Call some method of myChild
    this.myChild.myChildsPublicMethod()
  }

  render() {
    return <MyChild ref={ref => { this.myChild = ref; }} />
  }
}

// MyChild
// Just as demo using Pure components here.
// You could use the normal class notation.. 
const MyChild = () => <div>Ola</div>;
MyChild.someMethod = () => console.log('Ola');
```

More here https://zhenyong.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html